# KendoUI MVC: Sorting with a ViewModel

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using a ViewModel Class to bind to a KendoUI grid and it call works well until I try to sort (or filter). It all works ok until I try sort on **UserName**. I am sure it is because UserName is not a property of my entity model (ErrorLog)

```
public ActionResult ListErrors([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<ErrorLog> errorLogs = (IQueryable<ErrorLog>)db.ErrorLogs.Include(e => e.User).OrderByDescending(e => e.ErrorLogId);
        DataSourceResult result = errorLogs.ToDataSourceResult(request, errorLog => new ErrorLogViewModel
            {
                ErrorLogId = errorLog.ErrorLogId,
                Message = errorLog.AdditionalMessage,
                UserName = errorLog.User.UserName
            });
        return Json(result);
    }
```

This scenario doesn't seem to covered in the Kendo MVC documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the [KendoGridBinderEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinderEx/) project instead of [DataSourceRequest], together with AutoMapper this scenario should be work fine.

For a demo see [here](http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/Employee).

Comment: Interesting project - will take a look

Answer (score 3):

Solved by invoking ToDataSourceResult after my db query had run:

```
 public ActionResult ListErrors([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IQueryable<ErrorLog> errorLogs = (IQueryable<ErrorLog>)db.ErrorLogs.Include(e => e.User).OrderByDescending(e => e.ErrorLogId);
        DataSourceResult result = errorLogs.Select(errorLog => new ErrorLogViewModel
            {
                ErrorLogId = errorLog.ErrorLogId,
                Message = errorLog.AdditionalMessage,
                Timestamp = errorLog.Timestamp,
                UserName = errorLog.User.UserName
            }).ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: I had the same exact issue and your answer helped a lot. Next I need to figure out if I can do the same thing while still using AutoMapper.